# Compiling libgc with emscripten

Tags: javascript, gcc, clang, emscripten, libgc

I have a file called `foo.c` which contains the line `#include <gc.h>`, referencing the Boehm garbage collector library.

The emscripten documentation is says that external libraries must be compiled to bitcode first. So I compiled both `12.c` and `gc.c` to bitcode using `clang` and ran this command:

```
emcc 12.c gc.c
```

This compiles with warnings:

```
warning: incorrect target triple 'x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0' (did you use emcc/em++ on all source files and not clang directly?)
warning: unresolved symbol: llvm_objectsize_i64_p0i8
```

Running `a.out.js` gives me `missing function: llvm_objectsize_i64_p0i8`.

I'm assuming this is related to the warning regarding not using clang directly.

However, when I try to compile to bitcode via `emcc` it gives me the runaround and says

```
WARNING:root:emcc: cannot find library "gc"
fatal error: 'gc/gc.h' file not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Emscripten seems to be telling me I must use `emcc` to compile `libgc` but the documentation says I must compile to bitcode first.